# Kundera&MongoDB (in Play 2.1.3) bi-directional relationship doesn't get referenced correctly on the DB

Tags: mongodb, playframework-2.1, kundera

I'm using Kundera with Mongo and Play 2.1.3. My application has a User entity and a Document entity. The User has multiple Documents (oneToMany) and a Document belongs to a User.
    I first create and persist the User and the Documents can be added to that User.
    When I create a Document and persist it the userID that references the User is different from the userID of the User entity. And the User documents ArrayList is also always null.

```
So here's relevant parts of my entities:

@Entity(name="User")
@Table(name="User", schema="xpto@mongo")
public class User {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @Column(name="_id")
    private String userID;

    @Required
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    (...)

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="owner")
    private List<Document> documents;
    (...)
}


@Entity(name="Document")
@Table(name="Document", schema="xpto@mongo")
public class Document {

    @GeneratedValue 
    @Id
    @Column(name="_id")
    private String documentID;

    @Required
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    (...)

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="userID")
    private User owner;
    (...)
}

--

The user is created and persisted. The documents are created afterwards with something like the following:

public static void createDocument(String name, User user) {
EntityManagerFactory emf = Application.getEmf();
    Document document = new Document();
    document.setName(name);
    ...
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    document.setOwner(user);
    em.persist(document);
    em.close();
}

In the db:
db.User.find()
{ "_id" : "5211067576aae40da0595eb0", "name" : "Name of the user" (...) }

db.Document.find()
{ "_id" : "52113c1376aae337b4537028", "name": "name", "userID" : "52113c1376aae337b4537029" }

I was expecting the userID in the document to be the same as the User _id.
As I said when I try to access the user's documents ArrayList it's always null.

What am I doing wrong here? :)
Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on kundera-discuss group.